# AngularFirebase google signin idToken sometimes return user profile

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-authentication

This is a simple ionic and capacitor app, targeted at iOS and Android. We are authenticating users with AngularFirebase using the folliwng code:

```
private async loginGoogleWeb() {
  const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  provider.addScope('profile');
  provider.addScope('email');
  const credential = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

  this.updateUserData(credential);
}
```

Strange thing is that SOMETIMES the response in `credential.credential.idToken`includes the user profile (given_name, family_name, etc.). But most of the time, the idToken does not include this info.

Any idea as to why this could happen? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image: google idToken]

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of searching and reading, it turns out that Firebase does not return the idToken with the expected profile. According to one of the answers to this [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2158) posted in Firebase Github:

> As I said earlier your requests for features are reasonable, however
>   we have discussed these things in the past and have determined that we
>   won't add them to Firebase Auth right now. Since this issue tracker is
>   meant to track bugs in the SDK or feature requests that we plan to
>   implement, I am going to close this issue.

What I finally did is "exchange" the access_token provided by firebase and get the user profile using the following url: [https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token={firebase_provided_access_token}](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=%7Bfirebase_provided_access_token%7D)

Just posting this in case someone bumps into this problem in the future.